# Laravel - Eloquent filter where Left Join does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out how to make this query work. These two tables do not have a direct relation (i.e. hasOne, hasMany, etc). I am looking to only get back records from `client_vendor_relationship` that do NOT have a `collection_opt_in`. Since I don't have a way of doing `->whereDoesntHave()`, I am not sure how to get this data back.

```
client_vendor_relationship

| id | client_id | vendor_id | active |
|----|-----------|-----------|--------|
| 1  | 23484     | 1872      | 1      |
| 2  | 5643      | 345       | 1      |
| 3  | 431       | 4443      | 1      |


collection_opt_in

| id | client_id | vendor_id | year |
|----|-----------|-----------|------|
| 1  | 23484     | 23484     | 2020 |
| 2  | 23484     | 23484     | 2019 |
| 3  | 431       | 4443      | 2019 |
```

Current Query

```
$relationships = ClietVendorRelationship::where('active', 1)
->leftJoin('collection_opt_in', function($join){
  $join->on('client_vendor_relationship.client_id', '=', 'collection_opt_in.client_id')
  ->on('client_vendor_relationship.vendor_id', '=', 'collection_opt_in.vendor_id');
})
->where() // Not sure what to put here to ONLY get rows back that the left join didnt find entries for
->groupBy('client_vendor_relationship.id')
->get();
```

The end goal of this above query would to be to only get the row back from `client_vendor_relationship` with the id of `2`. I need to do this in Eloquent. I know I could easily just do a collection filter but the front end table I am using requires an eloquent query to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why using left join? while there is another straightforward ways?

you can use 'whereNotExists':

```
   $relationships = ClietVendorRelationship::where('active', 1)
            ->whereNotExists(function ( $query){
            $query->select('collection_opt_in.id')->from('collection_opt_in')->
                whereColumn('collection_opt_in.client_id', '=', 'client_vendor_relationship.client_id')-> 
whereColumn('collection_opt_in.vendor_id', '=', 'client_vendor_relationship.vendor_id');
                })
                ->groupBy('client_vendor_relationship.id')
                ->get();
```

also i must say i don't recommend using group by without aggregation

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!